# Cartesian3.distance - returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm trying to find the distance between a mouseclick and the nearest of a set of billboards.  My code is as follows:

```
var smallestDistance = -1;
var currentDistance = -1;
var nearestPeak;
var peakPosition;
var mousePosition = new Cesium.Cartesian3(ev.clientX, ev.clientY, 0.0);
for (var i = 0; i < peaks.length; i++) {
    peakPosition = peaks[i].position;
    currentDistance = Cesium.Cartesian3.distance(mousePosition, peakPosition);
    console.log( 'CESIUM: Distance to ' + peaks[i].name + ': ' + currentDistance + ' units.' );
    if (currentDistance < smallestDistance) {
        smallestDistance = currentDistance;
        nearestPeak = displayedPeaks[i];
    }
}
console.log( 'CESIUM: nearest peak is peak ' + nearestPeak.peakId );
if (smallestDistance != -1 && smallestDistance < 100000) {
    selectedPeak = nearestPeak;
}
```

The issue appears in the first console.log statement, where it displays:

```
CESIUM: Distance to peak 1: NaN units.
```

According to Cesium's documentation, it should be returning a number.  I could swear I did something similar in a past project and didn't have this issue.  I have a strong suspicion that I am missing and/or forgetting something very basic.  Can anyone advise?

**EDIT:**
I did some further debugging, and I am finding that peakPosition.x and peakPosition.y are both undefined, where peakPosition = peaks[i].position.  peaks[i] is still rendering as a billboard on the globe, and peakPosition is an object.  According to the Cesium documentation, it SHOULD be an object of type Cartesian3, which should have x and y members.  So why would those members be undefined?

**EDIT 2:**
I tried replacing this line:

```
peakPosition = peaks[i].position;
```

with this:

```
peakPosition = new Cesium.Cartesian3(this.peaks[i].position.x, this.peaks[i].position.y, 0.0);
```

and its x, y, and z members are always 0, 0, and 0.  I can't figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: From a quick look at their docs, `distance` is a static method. So could it be that `new` in front of the call to get the distance?

Comment: The new keyword is used to construct objects. Try removing it.

Comment: @CRice - thanks, I added that in after I started running into problems as a typo (I'd left off the new on the mousePosition = new Cesium.Cartesian3(ev.clientX, ev.clientY, 0.0); line, and when I added it in there I added it in on the distance line as well.  I was initially getting NaN as a a result, and now that I've fixed it I'm getting NaN again.  I was indeed missing something very basic, but unfortunately it didn't lead to the correct result.

Comment: Per your edit, where is the data for your `peaks` array coming from? If `peakPosition` doesn't have a `x` or `y` property, what does it have? As you say, if it were a `Cartesian3` object, it would have an `x` and `y`, so if it doesn't, we have to figure out what it actually is, and why its not what you are expecting.

Comment: Per second edit: the values are 0 because 0 is the default value for a Cartesian3 if it is left out. Since your position.x and position.y are undefined, it uses the default instead (which is 0). Can you tell us what the result of `console.log(peak[i].position)` is?

Comment: [object Object]
peaks is an array of Cesium.Entity rather than Cesium.Billboard, could that make a difference?  I've noticed javascript is funny about accessing member variables when it comes to nonspecifically typed variables, however, since position is returning an object I'm assuming it is a Cartesian3, so accessing the members of THAT object shouldn't be an issue as far as I can imagine.

Comment: Hmm. Disclaimer: I am not at all familiar with Cesium, but looking at their documentation for entity, it looks like type of its position field is a `Cesium.PositionProperty`, which according to the docs has no x nor y fields. However, it does have a `getValue(time)` method, which accepts a time value and returns a `Cesium.Cartesian3`. So, and this is a total shot in the dark, but try `peakPosition = peaks[i].position.getValue(new Cesium.JulianDate())`.

Comment: I changed it to a Billboard, whose position is def. a Cartesian3, with no change in behaviour.  that said, before, it was still a Billboard, stored in an array of Entities (which are a parent class of Billboard).

Comment: In that case I am afraid I'm at a loss. A `Cesium.Billboard`'s `position` field is indeed a `Cesium.Cartesian3`, so there should be no problem. My last guess is that either the coordinates you get from the mouse event are not valid, or your `peaks` array is, in fact, not an array of billboards. (And so I fully understand, are you sure that Entity is a parent class of Billboard? If it is, this would violate the LSP, since their position fields are not compatible (Cartesian3 doesnt seem to implement PositionProperty))

Comment: well, I found out you're right.  somehow peaks[i] is being accessed as if it were an Entity rather than a Billboard, and I can't figure out how to get a Cartesian3 from the PositionProperty.  At least now I know what is wrong though!  thanks.

Comment: you're right, it's not exactly a child class.  the relations are confusing between all the different type of displayable geometries in Cesium.  like I said though, at least now I know why I'm having this problem, now it's a matter of getting a Cartesian3 from an Entity.

Comment: Did `peakPosition = peaks[i].position.getValue(new Cesium.JulianDate())` not work? It seems that the `getValue` and `getValueInReferenceFrame` are the only two methods you can use to extract a Cartesian3. `PositionProperty` is just an interface, so without knowing which implementation you have underneath, the methods listed here are all you can use: https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/PositionProperty.html

Comment: you read my mind haha that's exactly what I just did.  somehow I didn't see that comment when you posted it the first time.  Can you write that up as an answer so I can accept?  because that worked.  thanks so much.

Comment: Done. Glad we figured it out. Victory tastes so sweet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, per our discussion we have discovered:

`peaks` is an array of `Cesium.Entity`s.

and

the `position` field of a `Cesium.Entity` is a `Cesium.PositionProperty`, which is an interface that has a method `getValue`, accepting a `Cesium.JulianDate` as its first parameter. So, putting all that together, the only change you need is:

```
peakPosition = peaks[i].position;
```

to

```
peakPosition = peaks[i].position.getValue(new Cesium.JulianDate());
```

Comment: This is mostly correct, but beware there's a memory allocation here with `new`, so you don't want to run this code at 60fps.  If you have a Cesium viewer or clock around, you can use `position.getValue(viewer.clock.currentTime)` instead.  And if you can guarantee that the position is in fact a `ConstantPositionProperty`, you don't need to pass in a time at all, just call `.getValue()`.